# Set the timer of carousel Dynamically

Tags: jquery, carousel

In jQuery,I want to set the timer interval for carousel dyanmically, 
for example for each image which I want to show on carousel , the interval can be change to different value. in examples I saw , time had been set at initialization time.
thanks for any help.

Comment: Which carousel library are you using?

Comment: @rwacarter I tested different libraries , in github used bxSlider, .. jq.carousel,...